# Rails ActiveRecord has_one association together with Object method override

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I came across a peculiar problem with `has_one` association in combination with an `Object` method override. Can somebody explain to me what is going on?

Here is how it goes:

I have a `has_one` relationship between `Supplier` and `Account`, like in the example of the `has_one` example used in Rails Guides.

Supplier:

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_one :account

  nilify_blanks
end
```

Account:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :supplier

  validates :supplier_id, :presence => true

  nilify_blanks

  def foo
    puts 'in account'
  end

  def to_s
    puts 'in account'
  end

end
```

I also have a method `foo` on `Object` as follows:

```
class Object
  def foo
    puts 'in object'
  end
end
```

When I call:

```
Supplier#account#to_s
```

I get 'in account'

When I call:

```
Supplier#account#foo
```

I get 'in object'

whereas I would expect it to print 'in account'

Does anybody have any clue why does this happen? Is this a bug in Rails ActiveRecord?

Thanks in advance

P.S. If you want, you can get a full fledged application that demonstrates the problem from here:

https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/test_association_and_object_method_override.git

Comment: did you try with account = Supplier.account and  account.foo ?

Comment: @NarenSisodiya yes. It has the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some investingation with one of my friends, got the way assoiciation works.

when we do Supplier.account it will give you object of AssociationProxy not an object of account. 
AssociationProxy delegates all methods to associated object if its definition not present in itself(it also delegates methods like class, inspect etc. so you can get the actual class name). 
Now, when we add foo in Object class its available in AssociationProxy and when you say Supplier.account it invokes foo from AssociationProxy not from account.

if you want to invoke foo from account use target method to get actual account object  like

```
Supplier.account.target.foo #=> foo from account
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It explains what is going on. Also, your `target` approach works. You can agree of course that this is a *workaround*, and requires that I will be using `target` on all my `has_one` associations and for all methods that I invoke, because I cannot be in place to know in advance which of my target model methods are defined on `Object` as well. Hence, your answer *answers* my question in half. I will be waiting for a while to see whether there is an answer to my question  about whether this is a bug in Rails or not, before accepting your answer.

Comment: And the question remains about `to_s`. Why `to_s` is invoked as expected. `to_s` already exists in `Object` and hence to `AssociationProxy`, doesn't?

Comment: to_s works because AssociationProxy class undefined all instance methods when it loaded in memory. Supplier.account.foo can also work if you overwrite object before loading AssociationProxy. I tried it putting Object overwriting code in enviroment.rb file at the top and got it working.